# How can I bond a fiber to waveguide grating coupler?

Tags: fiber-optics

I am wondering how can I bond a optical fiber to waveguide grating coupler. Should I use some type of glue? Or should I fix the fiber with a translation stage?

Comment: Can you share a photo, drawing, or specification document of the coupler?

Comment: https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=196, but really it depends on what you have and what you want

Comment: @ThePhoton Thank you for your answer. Possible figures could be figure 5 of https://www.osapublishing.org/oe/fulltext.cfm?uri=oe-21-9-10886&id=253090 or figure 18(a) of https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/8/7/1142. There seems many alternatives but I wonder which might be the most feasible one for beginners.

Comment: @Cryo Thank you. So I need to UV cure it.

Comment: @Rickyim. This is just one option. I guess you can find other ones, maybe cured by heating. But UV-curing does seem to be popular